# Will an object with linear velocity in outer space experience frame dragging effects?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, frame-dragging

Will an object moving non-accelerated in outer space experience frame-dragging? It seems the mass contributions to the strdss-energy-momentum tensor are distributed spherically symmetrical, and don't cause the object to accelerate. But what about the momentum contributions of the stars in the universe? Are there off diagonal elements in this tensor influencing the motion of the object and possibly even stopping it moving wrt the stars?

Answer (score 1):

If by “non accelerated” you mean that it is undergoing no proper acceleration, then yes. Objects in free fall still are affected by frame dragging. In fact, that is what Gravity Probe B tested, although to rather low experimental precision.

Comment: Maybe a separate question: is there a maximum of rotational framedragging? Say when the rotating mass can withstand the centrifugal forces, can an object falling radially towards the mass make one whole rotation?